# aws lambda to mysql written in python does not return the most up to date data until I change something and save the code again

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I use the following to connect my aws lambda to db:

https://www.isc.upenn.edu/accessing-mysql-databases-aws-python-lambda-function

here is the code which does the job:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
"""
This function inserts content into mysql RDS instance
"""
item_count = 0

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("create table Employee3 (EmpID  int NOT NULL, Name varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (EmpID))")
    cur.execute('insert into Employee3 (EmpID, Name) values(1, "Joe")')
    cur.execute('insert into Employee3 (EmpID, Name) values(2, "Bob")')
    cur.execute('insert into Employee3 (EmpID, Name) values(3, "Mary")')
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("select * from Employee3")
    for row in cur:
        item_count += 1
        logger.info(row)
return "Added %d items to RDS MySQL table" %(item_count)
```

The problem is when I try the lambda I get a result back fine but if I change the data in db and then send the request again while the lambda container is still running I do not see the updated data and I see the old data.
But when I save the lambda after a change just to kill the current container it starts loading the latest information.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, double check your response isn't being cached anywhere else (API Gateway, CloudFront, or whatever else you are using to call this lambda).

All variables outside of the handler in AWS Lambda are treated as global (to the individual instance of that lambda container at least).

The issue lies with something you have instantiated outside of the handler. The issue must lie with the connection (your conn variable). Move this code inside of the handler function.